# Implementation of a complex optimization formulation in Gurobi using Python

Tags: python, gurobi

I want to implement following optimization program and I found it very hard to do so:

> max.       alpha*(C'GC/|C|) + beta*((1-Var(1-3^{-VC}))*(mean(VC)/3))
>   
>   s.t.     |C| <= number and C in {0,1}

Whereas,

- C is a decision column vector of length m.
- |C| stands for norm 0 or sum of C vector.
- C' stands for transpose of C.
- G is a [m,m] matrix of non-negative real numbers.
- V is a [n,m] matrix of non-negative integers, n <= m.
- alpha and beta are constants (non-negative real numbers).
- "Var" and "mean" stand for variance and mean.
- "number" is a non-negative real number constant.

I am quit new to Gurobi. Any help to implement above formulation in Python is highly appreciated.